# Exception: URL fetch failure when loading data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to set up my machine to run Tensorflow 2. I've never used Tensorflow and just downloaded Python 3.7. I'm not sure if this is a problem with my machine or not. I followed the installation directions listed on [TensorFlow's website](https://www.tensorflow.org/install#install-tensorflow-2). I followed the installation instructions and everything seemed to be working.

MacOS 10.15.3

Python 3.7

Tensorflow 2

I created a small program just to test stuff out. This is what I have:

```
import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

data = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = data.load_data()
```

When I run  `data.load_data()` I get this error:

```
Downloading data from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1317, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1244, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1290, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1239, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 966, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1414, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 423, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 870, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1139, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/data_utils.py", line 263, in get_file
    urlretrieve(origin, fpath, dl_progress)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 247, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 543, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1360, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1319, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jacksonmelcher/Development/Personal/TensorFlow/tf_embeddings.py", line 12, in <module>
    (train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = data.load_data()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/datasets/fashion_mnist.py", line 75, in load_data
    paths.append(get_file(fname, origin=base + fname, cache_subdir=dirname))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/data_utils.py", line 267, in get_file
    raise Exception(error_msg.format(origin, e.errno, e.reason))
Exception: URL fetch failure on https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz: None -- [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)
```

Again, this is my first time using Tensorflow and Keras, but it seems like a connection issue with google's api service.

Any help would be greatly appreciated because I can't find anything.

Comment: The same code is working perfectly with my network. It could be an issue with your network.

Comment: I changed my network and I'm getting the same error. I should probably try an uninstall and fresh install of python

Comment: @RupeshGoud I'm getting the same issue when I try to use load_data() on mnist, and on the topic of it being a network issue, I also always get this "SSL certificate" verification failure thing when I try to use youtube-dl without the --no-check-certificate option. What exact network issue may cause such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can try download dataset use Chrome visit [this link is dataset of](https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz) 
and then change your code

```
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = data.load_data()
```

as

```
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = data.load_data(path='the file path you download')
```

hope can help you!

Answer (score 0):

If you run the following in the Python folder, it will work without any errors:

```
install Certificates.command
```

Answer (score 0):

`/Applications/Python\ 3.11/Install\ Certificates.command` should upgrade the certificates that came with installation.
Here is an output by running the command:

```
/Applications/Python\ 3.11/Install\ Certificates.command 
 -- pip install --upgrade certifi
Collecting certifi
  Obtaining dependency information for certifi from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/64/62/428ef076be88fa93716b576e4a01f919d25968913e817077a386fcbe4f42/certifi-2023.11.17-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  Using cached certifi-2023.11.17-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
Using cached certifi-2023.11.17-py3-none-any.whl (162 kB)
Installing collected packages: certifi
Successfully installed certifi-2023.11.17
```