# When importing tensorflow.keras ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have tried this code and I counter this problem.

```
import numpy as np

from tqdm.auto import trange, tqdm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras import layers
```

and I counter this problem

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[14], line 8
      4 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      6 import tensorflow as tf
----> 8 from tensorflow.keras import layers

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras'
```

Answer (score -1):

My latest Jupyter notebook uses Python 3.9, Jupyter server 2.7.0, Keras 2.13.1, and Tensor Flow 2.13.0.  I'm running in PyCharm 2023.3.2 Professional Edition.

My notebook imports look like this:

```
import os
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf

from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from tensorflow import keras
from keras import layers
```

No errors.  Works perfectly.

I added this to a Jupyter cell and executed it:

```
cifar10 = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
cifar10.head()
```

Here's the output I got:

```
Downloading data from https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar-10-python.tar.gz
```

It failed, but not because the name was wrong - it's a cert problem.  Here's the error I got:

```
Exception: URL fetch failure on https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar-10-python.tar.gz: None -- [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)
```

There's a workout from SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60255470/exception-url-fetch-failure-when-loading-data).   Try downloading the data, unzipping it, and reading the file from your local drive.

Comment: I tried this solution but when I complete the code ` cifar10=tf.keras.datasets.cifar10
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()` it give me this error `AttributeError: module 'keras.api._v2.keras' has no attribute 'datasets'`

Comment: Should be keras.datasets.cifar10.  Leave off the leading tf.

Comment: it is the same problem will counter ` AttributeError: module 'keras.api._v2.keras' has no attribute 'datasets' `